# Creating an XSLT Stylesheet

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I have two very simple documents, people.xml and people.xsl. I try to run the people.xml in a browser - it will not display anything; I am unable to even *inspect* the webpage. The two files exist in the same folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="people.xsl" ?>

<people>
    <husband employed="Yes">
    <name>Mark</name>
    <age>45</age>
    <wife>
        <wname>Janet</wname>
        <age>29</age>
    </wife>
    </husband>
    <husband employed="No">
    <name>Matt</name>
    <age>42</age>
    <wife>
        <wname>Annie</wname>
        <age>41</age>
    </wife>
    </husband>
</people>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="husband">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/><br/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you expect `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="people.xsl" ?>` to work in the browser make sure you load files over HTTP(S), not from the local file system. And it is not clear which output you expect or want to generate, there are built-in templates that output text nodes.

Comment: Use eg Visual Studio Code when you develop stylesheets, you can check the results in Notepad++ by using the XML tools. Or use one of the professional XML tools you can buy